# Get offset of a row after performing sort operation in sql

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I am using SQLite database.

Suppose I have rows with IDs 1 to 50. Then I perform `select` and `order by` operation.

Say, the result is IDs : 6,3,5,2,9,12,1,34,45,15.

Now, I want to know the offset of a particular row with given ID in the above result.e.g. offset of `ID 1` is 6.

Can I do this in a single query?

Comment: Why can't you simply count the rows as you're reading them from the cursor?

Answer (score 1):

put the query of `ordered` result into a `subquery` and use `count(*)` and check the id sequence:

**Example:**

---

*SCHEMA:*

```
CREATE TABLE tbl ("id" INTEGER,"val" INTEGER);
INSERT INTO tbl ("id","val")
VALUES
    (12,6),(1,7),(34,8),(6,1),(9,5),
    (45,9),(15,10),(3,2),(5,3),(2,4);
```

*QUERY:*

```
select id,(
           select count(*) 
           from (
                 select id,val 
                 from tbl order by val
                 ) b  
           where a.val >= b.val)-1 as offset
from tbl a
order by offset
```

*RESULT:*

```
id  offset
6   0
3   1
5   2
2   3
9   4
12  5
1   6
34  7
45  8
15  9
```

[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/cb31c/3)